# WebClient doesn't parse JSON response properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, lombok, dto

I hope someone can help me are several days I'm struggling with this problem.

I want to create a Rest Client with WebClient to retrieve the response from an API. So I created my Spring Project adding webflux, lombok and h2.
I created also a DTO class "CashAccount" and the following method:

```
public String retrieveAccountById(String accountId) {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri(GET_ACCOUNT_BY_ID_V4, accountId)
            .header("Auth-Schema", AUTH_SCHEMA)
            .header("apikey", API_KEY)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> {
                System.out.println("4xx error");
                return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("4xx"));
              })
              .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, response -> {
                System.out.println("5xx error");
                return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("5xx"));
              })
            .bodyToMono(String.class) // .bodyToMono(CashAccount.class)
            .block();
}
```

When I use ".bodyToMono(String.class)" all works fine and I receive the result:

```
    2:50:27.548 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG org.springframework.core.codec.StringDecoder - [43ed0ff3] [6449a63b-1, L:/192.168.1.72:60756 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] Decoded "{
  "status": "OK",
  "error": [],
  "payload": {"accountId":"80377145","iban":"IT10L01234567890 (truncated)...
```

Instead when I use ".bodyToMono(CashAccount.class)" i receive an object with all variables null:

```
23:17:31.236 [reactor-http-nio-2] DEBUG org.springframework.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonDecoder - [43ed0ff3] [77c463f4-1, L:/192.168.1.72:62306 - R:sandbox.io/210.278.152.97:443] Decoded [CashAccount(accountId=null, iban=null, abiCode=null, cabCode=null, countryCode=null, internationalCi (truncated)...]
```

Here my DTO class:

```
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class CashAccount {

        private String accountId; 
        private String iban; 
        ...
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you probably need a wrapper object that contains status, error and payload...

Comment: Hi Toerktumlare, Please can you give me more details?

Comment: your DTO class only represents whats in the payload variable. But the object in the log clearly shows that what you are receiving is an object with 3 parameters, status, error, and payload. So your DTO does not look like what is getting received. Your DTO only represents whats in the payload parameter. So you need to create another DTO that has 3 parameters, status, error and payload and use that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to map only the payload object to the CashAccount.
You should also have a status and error array in your dto.

Regarding your json response:

add a dto with missing fields

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ResponseDto {
  private String status;
  private List<String> error;
  private CashAccount payload;
}
```

then change .bodyToMono(ResponseDto.class)

I suggest you to test your mapping using @JsonTest

```
@JsonTest
class TestMarshalling {

@Autowired ObjectMapper mapper;

@Test
@SneakyThrows
void testmarshalling() {
  String response =
    "{\n"
        + "  \"status\": \"OK\",\n"
        + "  \"error\": [],\n"
        + "  \"payload\": 
     {\"accountId\":\"80377145\",\"iban\":\"IT10L01234567890\"}}";

  var cashAccount = mapper.readValue(response , ResponseDto.class);
  Assertions.assertNotNull(cashAccount.getPayload());
  Assertions.assertNotNull(cashAccount.getPayload().getAccountId());
  Assertions.assertNotNull(cashAccount.getPayload().getIban());
  }
}
```